# Most efficient way to do a horizontal sliding layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout, navigation

Take the layout below for example.

[image]

The black border represents the user screen.

The three small rectangles represent navigation buttons, when clicked, the corresponding color of the bigger box will slide horizontally to the user screen.

For example, when I click the small blue button, the big blue box (which is a div), will slide to the left going to the user screen, same goes for the other nav buttons.

Can you kindly point me to the right direction on how to achieve this?

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. They all work but I have to pick one so there :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for a content slider. An example of one that is similar to what you want would be this: http://bxslider.com/examples/auto-show-pager.

Alternatively, you could probably make your own:

http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/N3RZY/5/

HTML

```
<div class="viewport">
    <div class="inside">
        <div class="one"></div>
        <div class="two"></div>
        <div class="three"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="three-l">Green</div>
<div class="two-l">Blue</div>
<div class="one-l">Red</div>
```

jQ

```
$(".three-l").click(function() {
  $(".viewport").animate({scrollLeft: 400}, 500);
});
$(".two-l").click(function() {
  $(".viewport").animate({scrollLeft: 200}, 500);
});
$(".one-l").click(function() {
  $(".viewport").animate({scrollLeft: 0}, 500);
});
```

CSS

```
.viewport{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    overflow-x:scroll;

}

.inside{
    width:1000px;
    height:200px;
}

.inside div{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
}

.one{
    background-color:red;
}

.two{
    background-color:blue;
}

.three{
    background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A little rough around the edges but this should give you a decent reference:

http://jsfiddle.net/howlx5/5E9nn/

Comment: Hey mate! you should put the code in your answer, in case of your link gets deleted. So that, you'll ensure the availability of your answer and help other people in the future ;)

Answer (score 2):

Exactly the way you visualized it. Here's a little demo that does what you want: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/gQH38/2/). The code is pretty self-explaining, but I'd be glad to explain any part if it's vague. Here's a commented version of the JavaScript part:

```
$(".nav div").click(function() { //when a nav div is clicked
    var cur = $(this); //get the div that was clicked
    var idx = cur.index(); //get its index (0, 1 or 2)
    $($(".screen div")[idx]).animate({width: "100%"}); //show the appropriate screen-filling div
    $(".screen div").not(":eq(" + idx + ")").animate({width: "0"}); //hide all others
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank for this. I have a question. If I remove the background, how do I remove the contents of the inactive div from the screen. Right now they seem to stay in the screen. This is not a problem if there's background color, but if there's no background color, they're not hidden.