# USATODAY transition effect with url change

Tags: jquery, html

Sorry for my title, I don't know how to ask this...
If you go to www.usatoday.com and if you click in any link there is a transition (cool ones) I want to ask if someone know how to change the url example:

You click /news/ and your are on /sports/ it makes a transition as it is a slider but the url changes, as it is another page...

If someone understands what a want to ask, it will be very helpful.

PD Sorry for my bad english

Comment: I posted [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338302/how-to-make-browser-back-and-forward-work-on-a-single-page-layout/12338334#12338334) a few weeks ago, with some resources on how to change the URL even though you have a single-page structure. At least it can aid you in parts of your question.

Comment: HTML 5  at work there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think usatoday website is full Javascript application or say one page application. So there is no actual reloads.

URl Changing is new feature offered in HTML5 in a way to change the URL displayed in the browser* through javascript without reloading the page. It will also create a back-button event and you even have a state object you can interact with.

This means you won’t have to use the hash-hack anymore if you want add state to your AJAX-application, and search engines will be able to index your pages too.

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

You can use [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) to make this feature HTML4 browsers compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I already discovered, but I forgot to write it here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

They aren't actually links in the sense that they point the browser to a new URL. They've basically got the header area (which is somewhat static) and the content area, which is animated and dynamically loaded via Ajax calls.

Basically, everything is done using Javascript on the browser/client side of things, and using web services on the server side that return the actual content to be displayed.

Comment: Site looks very nice and modern. I would like to know if they used a framework or they wrote html5 from scratch.

Comment: From what I can tell by looking at it for a minute, it uses jQuery, Underscore.js, modernizr and require.js. They don't seem to be using any framework, so they probably rolled their own library for the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, a month ago. It can be acomplished with History API.

A well explanation can be found here: http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Best regards.